# How do I scale a character's feet with animation and constrain the hair to move in its new position in unreal engine?

Tags: animation, 3d, maya, unreal-development-kit

I want to make a character customization in unreal engine, how do I scale the character and constrain the hair and eyes to move in their new position ? I am using blendshapes. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Can we have more informations? are you exporting the rig into unreal? or just an alembic? do you want to do that into maya?

If you are working in maya, you can create rivets to constrain the hair and the eyes to the geo after the scale or any deformation.

Comment: I am exporting this to unreal engine, it will be a character customisation for a game. I think the solution is to make a slider to scale the bones, but I am not sure and I dont know how to do this.

Comment: What you describe seems to be a global scale to me, and it's not that easy to implement and depends completely on the way you builded your rig.

Comment: However if you do already have an animation, you can get an alembic from your model and then in another scene, import your alembic, create a cluster for the whole model (boyd, head and eyes) and scale the cluster, you will preserve the animation and the model, it will only be bigger. You can then create rivets onto your alembic to drive the hair. You might be able to do the same for the hair than for the body though,  rivets might not be necessary.